Lombok's @Builder annotation blocks unit test code coverage
I have the following declarations for a JavaBean class:
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClassNameDTO {
    // ...
}

When I run IntelliJ coverage configured for software coverage, I see my "ClassNameDTO" covered as "0%".
Trying various solutions for two days that maked me crazy, I discovered that commenting @Builder, my ClassNameDTO becomes covered as "100%":
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
//@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClassNameDTO {
    // ...
}

I MUST cover my software and I MUST have @Builder. How can I solve this problem? What bug exists in @Builder annotation code?
I tried a "lombok.config" file with:
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true

but that doesn't work for me.
